# How can I quickly convert to a list of lists, insert a string at the start of each element?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have read a file into the Python script using:

```
data=np.loadtxt('myfile')
```

Which gives a list of numbers of type 'numpy.ndarray', in the form:

```
print(data) = [1, 2, 3]
```

I need to convert this into a list of lists, each with a single-character string 'a' and one of the above values, i.e.:

```
[[a,1],
 [a,2],
 [a,3]]
```

(Note that 'a' does not differ between each of the lists, it remains as a string consisting simply of the letter 'a')

What is the fastest and most Pythonic way of doing this?
I have attempted several different forms of list comprehension, but I often end up with lines of 'None' displayed. The result does not necessarily have to be of type 'numpy.ndarray', but it would be preferred.

Also, how could I extend this method to data that has been read in from the file already as a list of lists, i.e.:

```
data2=np.loadtxt('myfile2',delimiter=' ')
print(data2)= [[1,2],
               [3,4],
               [5,6]]
```

To give the result:

```
[[a,1,2],
 [a,3,4],
 [a,5,6]]
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [1,2,3]
>>> a = np.empty([len(data),2], dtype=object)
>>> a
array([[None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
>>> a[:,0]='a'
>>> a
array([[a, None],
       [a, None],
       [a, None]], dtype=object)
>>> a[:,1]=data
>>> a
array([[a, 1],
       [a, 2],
       [a, 3]], dtype=object)
>>> data2=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> data2
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> b = np.empty([len(data2),3],dtype=object)
>>> b
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
>>> b[:,0]='a'
>>> b
array([[a, None, None],
       [a, None, None],
       [a, None, None]], dtype=object)
>>> b[:,1:]=data2
>>> b
array([[a, 1, 2],
       [a, 3, 4],
       [a, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```

**Edit:** In response to comment by OP you can label the columns by doing this:

```
>>> data2=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> c = zip('a'*len(data2),data2[:,0],data2[:,1])
>>> c
[('a', 1, 2), ('a', 3, 4), ('a', 5, 6)]
>>> d = np.array(c,dtype=[('A', 'a1'),('Odd Numbers',int),('Even Numbers',int)])

>>> d
array([('a', 1, 2), ('a', 3, 4), ('a', 5, 6)],
      dtype=[('A', '|S1'), ('Odd Numbers', '<i4'), ('Even Numbers', '<i4')])
>>> d['Odd Numbers']
array([1, 3, 5])
```

I don't know much about it but the array d is a record array.  You can find info at [Structured Arrays (and Record Arrays)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  I had trouble with the dtype of the "A" column.  If I put `('A', str)` then my a "A" column was always empty, `''`.  After looking at [Specifying and constructing data types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types) I tried using `('A', 'a1')` and it worked.

Comment: This works perfectly; thank you. Could I ask if you would know how to adapt the dtype such that it names the columns in each list? For example, in the final array above, the dtype name for each column would be 'A column', 'Odd Numbers', 'Even Numbers'?

I realise this is an entirely different question to the one I posted, so if you can't answer it, I understand!

Again, thank you very much!